# X is a steal/a real bargain/a rock-bottom price

Tags: synonyms

On [this Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/enjoyivy/?epa=SEARCH_BOX), I saw the following sentences:

> That’s a steal.
>
> = That’s a real bargain.
>
> = That’s a rock-bottom price.

The equals signs indicate they are interchangeable. But is the third one really equivalent to the first two?
In this regard, I'm thinking about what can serve as the subject in these sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the third sentence has a different meaning.

The first two both mean that you are getting a very good deal, which encapsulates price, but also quality and other factors that might be relevant to you.

Saying that something is being offered at 'a rock-bottom price' means that the price for the item is very low, but it does not mean that the item is a good deal, since the quality might be very low too.

Comment: Does it make sense to say, for example, "The desk is a rock-bottom price"?

Comment: Strictly speaking is doesn't make sense, since the desk itself is not a 'rock-bottom price', rather it is the price of the desk that is there.  You could say, 'The desk is AT a rock-bottom price.'